# AngularJs $resource, REST and Symfony2 FOSRestBundle

Tags: angularjs, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am using the FOSRestBundle, this bundle generates routes for me and pluralises those routes. For instance a GET request to */users.json* is different from a GET request to */user/15.json*

Its worth noting that a call to */users/15.json* fails.

More on this issue here https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/247

In my Angular app I use a `$resource` to create a RESTful call, the URL is a template as detailed here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

For example

```
$resource('http://example.com/:id.json')
```

Or

```
$resource('http://example.com/user/:id.json')
```

And there in is the problem, the `$resource` seems to accept a single URL template for the REST resource, but I have multiple ones because of the forced pluralisation from the FOSRestBundle.

I do not think hacking the FOSRestBundle is the answer, so what can I do with my usage of `$resource` in AngularJs to correct this issue?

Comment: You can do with $resource whatever you want, i.e.:

$resource('http://example.com/:mode:id.json', {id : '@id'}, 
query : {method:'GET', params: {mode:'users', id : ''}, isArray:true}),

Comment: @PetrAveryanov but my mode still needs to be set for each request depending on if its for a single entity or multiple entities. Simply setting `mode` to `users` doesn't help - I need to dynamically set it somehow depending on the request requirement.

Comment: If you don't like the way FOSRestBundle automatically manages the routes there's nothing stopping you from setting them up to work the way you want, or any real reason why you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set url for every method as third parameter - actions

```
angular.module("example", ["ngResource"])
  .factory("userService", function($resource) {
    return $resource("http://example.com/user/:id.json", {
      id: "@id"
    }, {
      'query': {
        url: "http://example.com/users"
      }
    })
  })
  .run(function(userService) {
    userService.query();

    userService.get({id:1});
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for this, its good to know. But, gah, seems so heavy handed and unnecessary given all the greatness that these two frameworks provide.

Comment: This has helped a lot now that I have tried it and changed my routes slightly. But what does this part do - `id: "@id"` - when removing it my code still works?

Comment: Sorry, it should be second parameter. I fix it. It means "as parameter id (key in object) will use id from passed object/entity"